# Passing Caught C# Exception as Parameter

Tags: c#, exception, rethrow

Will Jon Skeet feed me to his pet unicorn if I do something like the following?

```
private void TakeTheRisk()
{
    try
    {
        ...
        DoRiskyBusiness();
        ...
    }
    catch (SomeException ex)
    {
        ProcessAndRethrowException(ex);
    }
}

private async Task TakeYetAnotherRiskAsync()
{
    try
    {
        ...
        await DoEvenMoreRiskyBusinessAsync();
        ...
    }
    catch (SomeException ex)
    {
        ProcessAndRethrowException(ex);
    }
}

private void ProcessAndRethrowException(SomeException ex)
{
    ...
    throw; // given to understand `throw ex;` will lose stack trace, right?
}
```

Main motivation is to commonize exception processing logic.  This processing logic is non-trivial and I would prefer to not need to duplicate it.  Is it possible to somehow refactor it out of `TakeTheRisk` and `TakeYetAnotherRiskAsnyc` into `ProcessAndRethrowException` as above?

Comment: Have you tried this? IMO, you should just test/debug on your own, to get your desired result

Comment: You can also create an AggregateException, or a custom exception, with an `InnerException` being the target you want.

Comment: Note that `ProcessAndRethrowException` can't just use `throw;` - that's only valid in a catch block. You might want to consider using an exception filter instead.

Comment: Not sure I'm getting my point across.  The question is not how to catch this or that exception, so much as I have some non-trivial logic processing the exception, and I'd rather not duplicate it in two separate `catch` blocks.  Furthermore, and I'm editing the question to include this, while I would normally just encapsulate the whole `try`...`catch` into a common method, the second function is `async`, so I don't have that option.

Comment: BTW @JonSkeet you didn't answer my first question - am I unicorn snack?

Comment: @Bondolin: If you want to end up not actually catching the exception, but just processing it and then rethrowing it, an exception filter works well for that. Or put the `throw` part in the catch block as normal. Yes, it's fine to call a method with the exception as an argument